# How do you get the X and Y from a mouse click in DartPad?

Tags: javascript, dart, dart-html

I'm trying to create a new object in Dart where I click the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the X and Y coordinates using `offset` property. For more information, you can take a look into [documentation](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-html/MouseEvent-class.html). Your code should look like this:

Dart:

```
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  document.onClick.listen(findCoordinates);
}

void findCoordinates(evt) {
  querySelector('#hello').text = "x: " + evt.offset.x.toString() + " y: " + evt.offset.y.toString();
/// here you can create a whatever object you like
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="hello">This is a Heading</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Stefan mentioned the `offset` property will give you the X and Y coordinates.

Say you wanted to create an image where the mouse clicked, you could try something like this:

Dart:

```
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  querySelector('.imgContainer').onClick.listen(addImage);
}

void addImage(MouseEvent me) {
  DivElement imgContainer = querySelector('.imgContainer');
  ImageElement img = ImageElement()
    ..src = "https://dartpad.dev/dart-192.png"
    ..className = "dartLogo"
    ..style.left = "${me.offset.x - 25}px"
    ..style.top = "${me.offset.y - 25}px";
  imgContainer.append(img);
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dart Logo on Click</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="imgContainer"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

.dartLogo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
}

.imgContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Here's a live DartPad.dev example: [Create an image where the mouse clicked](https://dartpad.dev/b79bbbc44add42cb6a2bcbbec1dafd78)